# How to properly lock a resource while created in Java

Tags: java, initialization, java.util.concurrent

I have this singleton that creates objects, currently it looks like this:

```
public ApplicationManagerSingleton {
    ....
    private Map<String, Thing> map = new HashMap<String, Thing>();

    public Thing getThingById( String id ) {
       Thing t = null;
       if ( !map.contains(id) ) {
        t = longAndCostlyInitializationOfThing();
        map.put(id, t );
       }
       return map.get(id);
     }
 }
```

The obvious problem it has is, if two threads try to access the same thing, they may endup duplicating the thing.

So I used a lock:

```
 public ApplicationManagerSingleton {
      private Map<String, Thing> map = new HashMap<Sring, Thing>();
      public Thing getThingById(String id ) {
          synchronized( map ) {
             if (!map.contains(id)) {
                 t = initialize....
             }
             map.put(id, t);
           }
           returns map.get(id);
      }
 }
```

But now that's worst because I'll be locking the map for a while each time a new resource is being created in demerit of the other threads wanting different things.

I'm pretty sure it can be better with Java 5 concurrent package. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

What I want to avoid is to lock the class or the map for other threads that are interested in other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried these solutions and they failed at some point in my implementation, not saying they wont work in other scenarios.

What I finally end up doing was to use a [ConcurrentMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29) to check if the resource has been already requested or not. If not, it is created and stored somewhere else.

```
... 
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

... 
private ConcurrentMap<String, Boolean> created = new ConcurrentMap<>();
....
if ( created.putIfAbsent( id, Boolean.TRUE ) == null ) {
    somewhereElse.put( id, createThing() );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prevent creating the item multiple times which also blocking as little as possible, I would use two maps. One for holding a set of locks for use when creating the object and one for holding the objects.

Consider something like this:

```
private ConcurrentMap<String, Object> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
private ConcurrentMap<String, Thing> things = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Thing>();

public void Thing getThingById(String id){
    if(!things.containsKey(id)){        
      locks.putIfAbsent(id, new Object());
      synchronized(locks.get(id)){
         if (!things.containsKey(id)){
             things.put(id, createThing());
         }
      }
    }

    return things.get(id);
}
```

This will only block multiple thread attempting to get the same key, while preventing the `Thing` being created twice for the same key.

**Update**

Guava Cache example moved to new Answer.

Comment: I was exactly thinking in something like this... here's mine: https://gist.github.com/4454732

Comment: Great minds. I think the use of `putIfAbsent` helps to reduce a call of the lock map.

Comment: I thought that was pseudo haha.. looking at it :)

Comment: Don't forget the map double check inside the lock.

Comment: I was thinking about it, is that really needed?

Comment: Oscar, please see the update pointing you at Guava's `LoadingCache`. You can treat it as a `Map` and it has the threading you require built in.

Comment: In reply to your comment asking if it is really needed, yes it is. Remember that if two threads get past the first containsKey check, the second will be blocked until the first inserts into the map. The second then need to check again to find out if a previous thread has completed the insert.

Comment: Well now you have two answers in one, could you split them? :)

Comment: CacheBuilder always call load creating the `Thing` each time

Comment: Actually no, `CacheBuilder` will create a `LoadingCache` that will only call the `CacheLoader` once per key and store the returned value in a `Map` for later retrieval from the cache.

Comment: having multiple answers is discouraged. Is there a good reason to split them?

Comment: To downvote one and accept other :P Nah, seriously, if the answer is one of them it could be misleading to see the other. Anyway, I've just found my key es broken and that's why the `load()` method is invoked always :-/  :D

Answer (score 3):

Maybe ConcurrentHashMap can help you. As its name implies, it supports concurrent modifications.

To create a new element only once, you could do something like this:

```
private Map<String,Thing> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private final Object lock = new Object();
public Thing getById(String id) {
  Thing t = map.get(id);
  if (t == null) {
    synchronized(lock) {
      if (!map.containsKey(id)) {
        t = //create t
        map.put(id, t);
      }
    }
  }
  return t;
}
```

Only one thread is allowed to create new stuff at a time, but for existing values there is no locking whatsoever.

If you want to avoid locks completely you'd have to use 2 maps but it gets somewhat convoluted and it's only worth it if you really expect many threads to be populating the map continually. For that case it might be better to use FutureTasks together with a thread pool to create the objects asynchronously, minimizing the time the lock is in place (you still need a lock so that only one thread creates the new element).

The code would be something like this:

```
private Map<String,Future<Thing>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private final Object lock = new Object();
ExecutorService threadPool = ...;
public Thing getById(String id) {
  Future<Thing> t = map.get(id);
  if (t == null) {
    synchronized(lock) {
      if (!map.containsKey(id)) {
        Callable<Thing> c = //create a Callable that creates the Thing
        t = threadPool.submit(c);
        map.put(id, t);
      }
    }
  }
  return t.get();
}
```

The lock will only be in place for the time it takes to create the Callable, submit it to the thread pool to get a Future, and put that Future in the map. The Callable will create the element in the thread pool and when it returns the element, the get() method of the Future will unlock and return its value (for any threads that are waiting; subsequent calls won't lock).

Comment: So, the `Future.get()` will lock the thread until that particular future is ready?

Comment: That's right. Future.get() blocks until the resource is ready. After that, it returns its value immediately.

Comment: This failed to me in production for a 3 - 1 ms time frame. Changed to `concurrentMap.putIfAbsent()` call worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162353/how-to-properly-lock-a-resource-while-created-in-java/14346757#14346757

Answer (score 2):

After looking into it, I thing `Guava's` `LoadingCache` is probably a very nice solution for this. By default the `CacheBuilder` will create a cache that does not do any eviction (so it is just a map) and has the thread-blocking when loading for a key already built in.

[LoadingCache](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html)

[CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html)

```
 private Cache<String, Thing> myCache;

 MyConstructor(){
    myCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(
       new CacheLoader<String, Thing>() {
         public Thing load(String key) throws AnyException {
           return createExpensiveGraph(key);
         }
        });
 }

  public void Thing getThingById(String id){
    return myCache.get(id);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could immediatley insert a lightweight proxy in the map. The proxy will delegate to the real object once it is initialized, but block until then. Once the real `Thing` is initialized, it can replace the proxy in the map.

```
private Map<String, Thing> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public Thing getThingById(String id) {
    ThingProxy proxy = null;
    synchronized (map) {
        if (!map.containsKey(id)) {
            proxy = new ThingProxy();
            map.put(id, proxy);
        }
    }
    if (proxy != null) {
        proxy.initialize();
        map.put(id, proxy.getRealThing());
    }
    return map.get(id);
}

private class ThingProxy implements Thing {

    private Thing realThing;
    private CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @Override
    public void someMethodOfThing() {
        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
            realThing.someMethodOfThing();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    public void initialize() {
        realThing = longAndCostlyInitializationOfThing();
        countDownLatch.countDown();
    }

    public Thing getRealThing() {
        return realThing;
    }
}
```

This locks on the map, but only briefly to create a proxy and put it if needed.

The code for the proxy may become laborious, in which case you may be better of creating a proxy using reflection (see [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html))

Comment: could you post some code to demo your idea? i dont quite follow.

Comment: I will, just give me some time

Comment: I was thinking something along this line, but instead to put the lock on the map, so the following thread only locks that part...

Comment: My final suggestion is similar to this, but uses Futures instead of a custom proxy.

Comment: That's also a great idea. But you do need to keep a Thread around (or get one from a pool) to initialize the entries. My approach just gets the work done by the thread that would be waiting anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `ConcurrentHashMap`.  This one can be accessed by multiple threads without problem.

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` does not have a mechanism to ensure that you don't do the work of creating the item twice.

Comment: Hello!! :) But it won't prevent from creating duplicate resources, see: https://gist.github.com/4454674

Comment: Hey Theo, you were much closer that what I initially thought